# Am trying to create a web chat app when i send a message am having this error in console

Tags: javascript, php, json

I suspect the forEach line has the problem. Please, how do I go about it because my PHP code works well, my database interaction is perfect, just the JavaScript functions to show the message I am having issues with. i have moved the renderMessage function yet no change

**Error:**

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 6255ms
    (index):30 Uncaught ReferenceError: renderMessage is not defined
        at (index):30
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Object.success ((index):28)
        at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
        at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

**Here is my index .php code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <script >
    var from = null, start=0, url='chat.php';
    $(document).ready(function(){
         from = prompt("please enter your name");
        load();
        $('form').submit(function (e){
            $.post(url,{
                message: $('#message').val(),
                from: from
            });
            $('#message').val('');
            return false;
        })
    });

    function load(){
        $.get(url + '?start=' + start, function(result){
            if(result.items){
                result.items.forEach(item=>{
                    start = item.id;
                    $('#messages').append(start, renderMessage(item));
                });
                $('#messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight});
            }
            load();
        });
    }

    function renderMesssage(item){
        let time = new Date(item.created);
        time =`${time.getHours()}: ${time.getMinutes()< 10 ? '0': ''} ${time.getMinutes()}`;
        return `<div class="msg"> <p> ${item.from} </p>${item.message}<span>${time} </span></div>`;
    }
  </script>
    <style>

        body{
            margin:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            font-family: 'Lucida Sans','Lucida Sans Regular','Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode'
        }
        #messages{
            height: 88vh;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        form{
            display: flex;

        }
        input{
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 5px;
            appearance:none;
            -webkit-appearance:none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #message{
            flex: 2;
        }
        .msg{
            background-color: #dcf8c6;
            padding:5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            width: fit-content;
        }
        .msg p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .msg span{
            margin-left: 15px;
            font-size: 0.7rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="type message..." >
        <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.php which handles database**

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","chat");
if($db->connect_error){
    die("connection failed" .$db->connect_error );
}

$result=array();
$message=isset ($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;
$from=isset($_POST['from']) ? $_POST['from'] : null;

if(!empty($message) && !empty($from)){
    $sql ="INSERT INTO `chat` (`message`, `from`) VALUES ('".$message. "', '".$from. "')";
    $result['send_status']= $db->query($sql);
}

$start=isset($_GET['start']) ? intval($_GET['start']) : 0;
$items= $db->query("SELECT * from `chat` WHERE `id` > ".$start);
while($row=$items->fetch_assoc()){
    $result['items'][]=$row;
}

$db->close();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

?>

thats all

Comment: Where do you do a `setTimeout()`? Complete the code please

Comment: i didn't use that

Answer (score 0):

Does it change anything if you move the renderMessage above the code that calls it? Also, you have the character s three times in the title of the function. If you correct that, it might help.